# creating custom vertical seekbar, android

Tags: android-widget, android

In my application I require a vertical seekbar, something like this:
[image: vertical seekbar]

I dont know how to modify android's default seekbar to look like this ! also I dont know any external 3rd party library which provides this kind of seekbar..

Is there any way I can get this !

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont modify it...u create your own view:

```
package android.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.rotate(-90);
        c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
                onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just creating a vertical seekbar, i.e 90 degree rotated verion of default android's seekbar. But I want a seekbar where some portion of width is also highlighted when seekbar is moved !

Comment: i dont get what you really want? with this u have the same functionality like the default seekbar that is vertical...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the backround to be higlighted when the seekbar is moved you can capture the MotionEvent by overriding onTouchEvent and do whatever you want with the background color/image for your layout.  By the way, can you better explain what you mean by "I want a seekbar where some portion of width is also highlighted when seekbar is moved"?

Comment: after a night of sleep i would say he needs the setProgress method from parent class progressbar

Comment: yeah exactly. I think finally you got it ! I want to create a seekbar exactly same as in the pic that I have uploaded here.!

Comment: dont see the pic, but i assume u needed the setProgress